# Permanent database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, psql

This is more a logic question than anything else.

I want to create a database (model) in ruby on rails that holds information that I do not want to be deleted when I reset the database. I also want the information saved in this database to automatically be pushed to production when I push my project.

I have googled but found nothing relevant and I feel like I am missing something obvious. How would I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can seed your database with data. Using db/seeds.rb plus rake db:seed

According to official documentation

```
Rails has a 'seeds' feature that should be used for seeding a database with initial data. It's a really simple feature: just fill up db/seeds.rb with some Ruby code, and run rake db:seed:
5.times do |i|
  Product.create(name: "Product ##{i}", description: "A product.")
end

This is generally a much cleaner way to set up the database of a blank application.
```

Taken from http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#migrations-and-seed-data

So this will enable you to re-create your data automatically as part of the migrations when you move to production plus it will also populate test databases for you as well as get the development database into the state you need.

Obviously seeds.rb is just a ruby file. You can put any Ruby code you like in it. For example code to populate tables from a spreadsheet or xml document.

Answer (score 2):

[**rails_config**](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config)

Further to the `seeds` idea forwarded by `jamesw`, you *may* wish to use a static data store (typically in `yml` format), to hold your data as constants.

This is most openly displayed with the new `secrets.yml` feature of Rails 4.1, and there are more gems which help with this too. Typically [`rails-config`](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config):

```
#app/settings.yml
option:
  setting: "value"
  setting2: "value"
```

This allows you to create a series of data (we use it for our company details - address etc), which can be accessed by `Settings.option.setting`:

[image]